# How to require a file relative to requirer?

Tags: node.js, configuration, configuration-files

I'm developing a library where **I would like to load one or more files relative to the requirer**. To better illustrate this:

```js
// ~/app.js
import { horn } from 'unicorn'
horn.load()

// ~/node_modules/unicorn/horn.js
export default {
  load() {
    require('./user.config.js') // Here I would like to load the user config
                                // relative to "~/app.js"
  }
}
```

I tried inspecting the global `require` and its `parent` property but it only give me a filename without more context.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you have available:

```
module.parent
```

This is the module handle of the first module to load this module.  Because module handles are cached, this will only reflect the first module that loaded you.

```
module.filename
```

This is the fully qualified filename to a module.  So, if you want the fully qualified filename of the parent module, you could use this:

```
module.parent.filename
```

If you just want the path of the parent module so that you could load something from that directory, then you can split off the path from the filename to get just the path using the `path` module.

```
path.dirname(module.parent.filename)
```

If you want to load a file from that directory, you could do this:

```
let fileToLoad = path.join(path.dirname(module.parent.filename), "user.config.js");
let config = require(fileToLoad);
```

---

You will have to remember the caveat above that `module.parent` only returns the very first module to load you because after that the module is cached and just the original module handle is returned (it is not reloaded).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the details and the word of advice. I will give a try when I get some time, then I will come back to accept the answer.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo - Were you able to try this?  Did it work for you?  Is it appropriate to mark best answer to indicate to the community that the question is now done?

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but I will. I have been sucked up with other stuff. Sorry!